# Magento 2.3 - Add product to cart issue with store view

Tags: magento2, orders, multistore, addtocart, quote

I have two stores with id 1 and 2. Am trying to add product programmatically using below code 
`$params = array(
            'form_key' => $this->_formkey->getFormKey(),
            'product' => $productId, //product Id
            'qty'   => $qty //quantity of product

            );

        $this->_cart->addProduct($product_coll, $params);
        $this->_cart->save();`

Checkout flow works well for the store 1.
But for store 2, when I add any product to cart using above script. It is adding it to the store 1. I found out this when I looked into the magento **quote table** . Even though am in store 2, when i add product to cart the quote tables shows it is assigned to store 1. 
So the order was also place in store 1 instead of store 2.

Can anyone please help me with this ASAP?

Answer (score 0):

Set store id when get product

```
$product_coll=$this->productRepository->getById($productId, false, $storeId)
```

Comment: Actually am using custom REST API to add products to cart and to fetch all the cart items. When I return the store id from that API it return only the default store_id as 1 even if i'm in store 2. 
Can you please tell me what error i would have done during the custom API creation?

Comment: Is custom REST API is always in default scope? How shall I make that to other stores scope?

Answer (score 0):

I was using my custom REST API to add, fetch and remove the products to and from cart.

**The problem was I didn't specify the Scope section in the REST API url as per the Magento Documentation**

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/index.html

`<HTTP verb> http://<host>/rest/<scope>/<endpoint>`

In place of **scope** we should pass our **store code**

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace Indexiz\Addtocart\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
     */
    protected $cart;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    protected $product;

    protected $productRepository;

    protected $_storeManagerInterface;

    // protected $_productFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface  $_storeManagerInterface,
        // \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_storeManagerInterface = $_storeManagerInterface;
        // $this->productFactory = $_productFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $params = array();
            $params['qty'] = '1';//product quantity
            /*get product id*/
            // custom-price-set
            // $params['price']='100';
            //productId
            $skuId =$_GET['sku'];
            // $_product = $this->productFactory->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
            $currentStore = $this->_storeManagerInterface->getStore();
            $currentStoreId = $currentStore->getId();
            
            $_product = $this->productRepository->get($skuId);
            // $_product = $this->product->load($pId); 
                if ($_product){
                    $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
                    $this->cart->save();
                }
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Add to cart Successfully.'));
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException(
                $e,
                __('%1', $e->getMessage())
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('error.'));
        }
        
        // print_r($currentStoreId);
        // die();
        // $this->getResponse()->setRedirect('/checkout');

        /*cart page*/
        if ($currentStore->getId()=='2') {
            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect('/se/checkout');
        }elseif ($currentStore->getId()=='3') {
            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect('/de/checkout');
            
        }elseif ($currentStore->getId()=='4') {
            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect('/da/checkout');
            
        }else{
            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect('/checkout');

        }
    }
}
```